# On Cart page, Estimate Shipping and Tax section not updating shipping rates on change of state and zipcode

Tags: magento-2.1, knockoutjs, requirejs

My cart page only fetches **shipping rates** first time on the **initial page load**. After that changes in state and ***zip-code*** is not updating the shipping rates section.

Can someone point out what can be wrong and **how to debug** this? I am basically looking for an understanding of *how this section works*. And which code parts to look at to identify the problem?